# Specify Vertex Quality in OBJ File

Tags: vertex, obj

I've got a program that prints OBJ files in the format

```
# x y z r g b format opens with MeshLab only (http://meshlab.sourceforge.net/)
v xVal yVal zVal rVal gVal bVal
v xVal yVal zVal rVal gVal bVal
v xVal yVal zVal rVal gVal bVal
v xVal yVal zVal rVal gVal bVal
.....
```

And I'd like to start including "quality" data as well.  I'm having a hard time finding an example that shows the correct way to format an OBJ file with quality data, does anyone have one they can share with me?

Thank you

Comment: That's not even a proper OBJ format, that's a similar-looking file format. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file for original OBJ specifications. What file format are you /really/ working with?

Comment: I believe that it is proper OBJ format.  Looking at the Wikipedia page that you reference, it appears that the basic standard does not include RGB values as mine does, but in the discussion under "Geometric Vertex" it says "Some applications support vertex colors, by putting red, green and blue values after x y and z."

Comment: And if I'm not using OBJ file format, I sure don't know what I am using.  But I'm calling them .obj and Meshlab ingests them properly.

Comment: @stranger Could you define "quality data"? Is this for LOD?

Comment: @VaughanHilts I'm not sure what LOD is.  I'm working with a 3D scanner, so I get a point cloud, but not all of the points are accurate.  There are a few ways I can make a guess as to the accuracy of a given point, and I would like to use the quality parameter as a sort of confidence index.

Comment: If this is non standard, why not just save another file in your own format, then? It'll save you some grief. From what I can tell, the Waveform OBJ format does not support any sort of metadata saving.